# rviz - how to pub /tf topic msg ( from /dynamic_joint_states)

Tags: ros2, rviz, joint-state-publisher, tf

I solved it.
Just my mistake about urdf.xacro
Thankyou

I'm currently experiencing an issue where I'm not getting any output in `/tf`.

I learned from a previous question that `joint_state_pub` is responsible for outputting tf topics for `dynamic joints` (non-fixed).
([A problem occurs in tf while outputting robot_description to rviz](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/a-problem-occurs-in-tf-while-outputting-robot-description-to-rviz))

So, I checked what topics were created in the file I was working on.
We confirmed that the output is normal for `/joint_states` and `/dynamics_joint_states` as follows:
(It may be unrelated, but these are output from `jsp`)

I just don't know what to do.

++))This really drives me crazy.
Today, I will burn my last breath with this and fall asleep with tears in my eyes.
That is, during the xacro conversion process, the contents of the urdf file were not recognized, so I had to modify it. To find out if this was the problem, I tried converting urdf by inserting it into an existing example file, and the same phenomenon occurred. In the end, it may be that I did not follow the rules of the urdf file.
I'm wrong and I hope I can correct it today. See you later

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: my mistake about urdf.xacro

Comment: i need ti delete this question?